# Why are image attributes different when selecting element vs. inspecting?

Tags: image, function, callback, web-inspector

The following function is called when my page loads to set the default src and data attributes for an image element, and can also be called in the following click event handler to change the elements src and data attributes on the fly. The function sets the default attributes correctly when the page loads, and also in the click handler (when I inspect the image element the attributes have been changed) however when I select the element the default attributes will not change no matter how many times I run the click event. Does this have something to do with my callback?

```
function changepics(newbreed) {

  var pic = "<?php echo $breedpic ?>";
  var path = "../Mazi/images/";
  var getpic = path+pic;

// set default
  $('#breedimage').attr({
"src":getpic,
"data":pic
});

//change default    
if(newbreed) {
$.post('myquery.php', {"newpic" : newbreed}, function(result) {
  var newpic = result;  
  var newpic = path+newpic;
      $('#breedimage').attr({
    "src":newpic,
    "data":newbreed
    });
    });

    setfilter(currpage, newbreed);  
    }
```

}

```
$('#table2').on("click", ".breed", function() {
newbreed = $(this).text();
changepics(newbreed);
});
```

Answer (score 0):

When I made my selection inside the success handler of $.post I was able to retrieve the attributes of the new image.